# Jenkings git for-each-ref

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I get a result similar to git for-each-ref on jenkins pipline?
I have tried using git plugin for jenkins, but it seems to have only information about current branch.
I have also tried using external groovy script, but it doesn't seem to have this ability.
To my understanding, there is something on python called GitPython, but it requires a higher version of python than there is available on Jenkins.
When I run the following

```
def branches = git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(HEAD) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) - %(color:red)%(objectname:short)%(color:reset) (%(color:green)%(committerdate:relative)%(color:reset))'
```

I get

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 21: expecting '}', found 'git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format=' @ line 21, column 21.
```

Comment: Add a step with a shell script (inline or from a file), and run `git for-each-ref ...` in it. The things (software, files, database ...) that are "available in Jenkins" depend on what is installed *on the runner* (the machine that actually executes the job)

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. I have tried that using bat, but it didn't work. See edit.

Comment: the error message points to a syntax error (`expecting '}', found ... `). Read the docs and check your script

Comment: This is how it runs on local shell. I don't know how to adapt it to jenkins and groovy